# How to define template to automatically create logger whenever creating any class with corresponding type?

Tags: java, spring, logging, intellij-idea

Could you help me define code preset/template so that whenever I create any class the line would be inserted as well. How to do it in IntelliJ?

```
private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TheClassWithinWhichContained.class);
```

E.g.

```
@RestController
public class EndPointsController {

// after I defined the class IntelliJ should suggest me/or forcefully create
private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EndPointsController.class);
}
```

Also correct me if I am wrong but I don't follow static notation for loggers as within IoC any component is singleton therefore there is ever going to be only one instance?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself:

Search in settings for "File and Code Templates"-> Class:

Replaced existing with slightly modified version:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ${NAME} {
private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(${NAME}.class);
}
```

Not sure everyone is same lazy as I am but... :-) Hopefully it helped somebody.